# Resolution of the dependency failed when using CacheOutput attribute in WebApi2 project

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET WebApi2 project I decided to use the [Strathweb.CacheOutput.WebApi2 package](https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache) to provide caching and e-tag functionality. However, after putting the CacheOutput attribute I started to get an error:

```
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "WebApi.OutputCache.Core.Cache.IApiOutputCache", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, WebApi.OutputCache.Core.Cache.IApiOutputCache, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
```

Obviously, the package's internal DI container cannot resolve a cache provider.

The way I use the attribute:

```
[HttpGet, Route("")]
[CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 60 * 60 * 4, ServerTimeSpan = 60 * 60 * 4)]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(
    string products,
    int? startYear = null,
    int? endYear = null,
    int? drillDownYear = null,
    int? drilldownMonth = null,
     string callback = "")
    {
       ...
    }
```

Just to note, I am also using Unity in my application as a DI container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lib uses the following logic to find cache provider (the first match is used):

1. Checks for a `Func<IApiOutputCache>` in the `Properties` of your `HttpConfiguration`
2. Check in the registered `IDependencyResolver`
3. uses `new MemoryCacheDefault()`

Typically `IDependencyResolver` will return null when registration is not found - i nthis case looks like your Unity implementation is throwing an Ex instead.

You can mitigate that by switching to a better DI :) or just register a singleton of `new MemoryCacheDefault()` as `IApiOutputCache` in your Unity container.

Comment: check the dependency resolver for unity used here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver, you should return null not throw on resolution failed

Comment: Singleton registration seemed to be working, but after solving one dependency it falls with others :-) So I came up with your second suggestion: create (basically copypaste) a custom unity resolver. Unity.Mvc creates UnityWebApiActivator class on install, and the UnityDependencyResolver should be replaced with a CustomUnityResolver, which comes from with a code the link above.

Comment: Filip W answered this on a [later github issue](https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache/issues/89). Basically, these 2 lines are needed on app start: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.CacheOutputConfiguration().RegisterCacheOutputProvider(() => new MemoryCacheDefault());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.CacheOutputConfiguration().RegisterDefaultCacheKeyGeneratorProvider(() => new DefaultCacheKeyGenerator());`